# How to fix tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError, Registered devices: [CPU], Registered kernels: device='GPU'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am training  using the following code and getting the error. Do I need a GPU enabled version of tensorflow?
https://github.com/xyf513/SpiderCNN

```
> python train.py
```

Tensor("Placeholder_2:0", shape=(), dtype=bool, device=/device:GPU:2) 32 1024 3 1024 Tensor("strided_slice:0", shape=(32, 1024, 3), dtype=float32, device=/device:GPU:2) (32, 1, 1024, 3) Tensor("delta/Sum:0", shape=(32, 1024, 1024), dtype=float32, device=/device:GPU:2) 20 Tensor("delta/Slice:0", shape=(32, 1024, 20), dtype=int32, device=/device:GPU:2) Tensor("delta/Slice_1:0", shape=(32, 1024, 20), dtype=float32, device=/device:GPU:2) 2021-06-03 17:37:21.423951: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations. 2021-06-03 17:37:21.424011: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations. 2021-06-03 17:37:21.424021: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations. 2021-06-03 17:37:21.424025: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations. 2021-06-03 17:37:21.424029: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use FMA instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations. Traceback (most recent call last):   File "train.py", line 281, in 
train()   File "train.py", line 148, in train
sess.run(init, {is_training_pl: True})   File "/home/admin/anaconda/envs/tf_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 895, in run
run_metadata_ptr)   File "/home/admin/anaconda/envs/tf_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1124, in _run
feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)   File "/home/admin/anaconda/envs/tf_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1321, in _do_run
options, run_metadata)   File "/home/admin/anaconda/envs/tf_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1340, in _do_call
raise type(e)(node_def, op, message) **tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'SelectionSort' with these attrs.  Registered devices: [CPU], Registered kernels:   device='GPU'
[[Node: delta/SelectionSort = SelectionSortk=20, _device="/device:GPU:2"]]**

My environment is:

```
tensorflow                1.3.0                         0
tensorflow-base           1.3.0            py27h0dbb4d0_1
tensorflow-tensorboard    1.5.1            py27hf484d3e_1
cudatoolkit               8.0     3

>nvcc --version
Built on Fri_Nov__3_21:07:56_CDT_2017
Cuda compilation tools, release 9.1, V9.1.85
```

Comment: I am adding some information that are potentially useful to answer. This link details how to implement a kernel for a tensorflow operator. 
https://github.com/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/r1/guide/extend/op.md
Of particular interest is the line: 
REGISTER_KERNEL_BUILDER(Name("ZeroOut").Device(DEVICE_CPU), ZeroOutOp);
 A similar call for my code is in:  https://github.com/xyf513/SpiderCNN/blob/master/tf_ops/grouping/tf_grouping.cpp.  I have tried to change  the argument of Device to DEVICE_CPU at the two places in the cpp, but it didn't help.

Comment: Error is because Tensorflow-gpu is not configured properly and check right version of CUDA and cuDNN are installed. `tf.test.is_gpu_available` return False? If that's the case, then it definitely means the GPU is not configured correctly.Thanks!